# MirrorDisplays error every 30 seconds in system.log

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, error, daemons

I'm seeing an error every 30 seconds in the system log, using the Console app, complaining about `MirrorDisplays` service only running for 0 seconds.

```
Nov  5 22:45:22 computer com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.preference.displays.MirrorDisplays): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Nov  5 22:45:52 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Nov  5 22:45:52 computer com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.preference.displays.MirrorDisplays): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Nov  5 22:46:22 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Nov  5 22:46:22 computer com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.preference.displays.MirrorDisplays): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Nov  5 22:46:52 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Nov  5 22:46:52 computer com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.preference.displays.MirrorDisplays): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

It doesn't matter if I have no external display or use an external display at the same time.  How do I turn off this repeated error in the logs?

Comment: Pile you clarify this with an edit. Are you eying to suppress the messages and not change your setup?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same log complaints. 
They are the result of macOS detecting the secondary HDMI display and some code quality issue.

Uncheck "System Preference > Display > Show mirroring options in the menu bar when available." After reboot the log output will be gone.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this problem on my system by modifying the LaunchAgent file to only load in the LoginWindow.

In addition to eliminating the errors every 30 seconds in the log, it also appears to also have resolved an issue where my display would not turn off, regardless of the setting in Energy Saver. So, I'm pretty happy.

The steps I took were as follows:

1. Disable System Integrity Protection so you can edit the .plist file.  Do this by rebooting into the recovery partition with cmd-R, open Terminal from the Utilities menu, and type:

   ```
   csrutil disable
   ```
2. Reboot into yoru system, then edit the .plist file with this command:

   ```
   sudo vi /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.preference.displays.MirrorDisplays.plist
   ```
3. Comment out the line that causes the MirrorDisplays tool to load.  Change this line:

   ```
         <string>Aqua</string>
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   <!--  <string>Aqua</string>   -->
   ```
4. Then, reboot and reenable System Integrity Protection using the recovery partition as described above and type:

   ```
   csrutil enable
   ```
5. Reboot and enjoy a clean log file!

Answer (score 3):

unchecking "displays have separate spaces" in System Preferences ->Mission Control worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Editing the plist file as explained in [Carl Hewitt's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/311507) caused windows that extended across two monitors to only show on one of the two screens. The other portion of the window simply disappeared.

**The following resolved the issue for me**:
Launch System Preferences, select *Displays* and uncheck "Show mirroring options in the menu bar when available."

System: 2017 27" iMac High Sierra 10.13.6 with two additional 27" ASUS displays connected via HDMI at the display.
Credit to Allan & Bath Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just within your session, enter:

```
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.preference.displays.MirrorDisplays.plist
```

and check it's OK:

```
grep Displays /var/log/system.log
```

8640 processes and failure logging each day suppressed!